# Why doc2vec is giving different and un-reliable results?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, similarity, doc2vec

I have a set of 20 small document which talks about a particular kind of issue (training data). Now i want to identify those docs out of 10K documents, which are talking about the same issue.

For the purpose i am using the doc2vec implementation:

```py
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    
# Tokenize_and_stem is creating the tokens and stemming and returning the list
# documents_prb store the list of 20 docs
tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=tokenize_and_stem(_d.lower()), tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(documents_prb)]
max_epochs = 20
vec_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                dm =1)

model.build_vocab(tagged_data)
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    print('iteration {0}'.format(epoch))
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
    # decrease the learning rate
    model.alpha -= 0.0002
    # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

model.save("d2v.model")
print("Model Saved")

model= Doc2Vec.load("d2v.model")
#to find the vector of a document which is not in training data
    
def doc2vec_score(s):
    s_list = tokenize_and_stem(s)
    v1 = model.infer_vector(s_list)
    similar_doc = model.docvecs.most_similar([v1])
    original_match = (X[int(similar_doc[0][0])])
    score = similar_doc[0][1]
    match = similar_doc[0][0]
    return score,match


final_data  = []

# df_ws is the list of 10K docs for which i want to find the similarity with above 20 docs
for index, row in df_ws.iterrows():
    print(row['processed_description'])
    data = (doc2vec_score(row['processed_description']))
    L1=list(data)
    L1.append(row['Number'])
    final_data.append(L1)
     
with open('file_cosine_d2v.csv','w',newline='') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['score','match','INC_NUMBER'])
    for row in final_data:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

But, I am facing the strange issue, the results are highly un-reliable (Score is 0.9 even if there is not a slightest match) and score is changing with great margin every time. I am running the `doc2vec_score` function. Can someone please help me what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

First & foremost, try not using the anti-pattern of calling train multiple times in your own loop.

See this answer for more details: [My Doc2Vec code, after many loops of training, isn't giving good results. What might be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801052/my-doc2vec-code-after-many-loops-of-training-isnt-giving-good-results-what-m/62801053#62801053)

If there's still a problem after that fix, edit your question to show the corrected code, and a more clear example of the output you consider unreliable.

For example, show the actual doc-IDs & scores, and explain why you think the probe document you're testing should be "not a slightest match" for any documents returned.

And note that if a document is *truly* nothing like the training documents, for example by using words that weren't in the training documents, it's not really possible for a `Doc2Vec` model to detect that. When it infers vectors for new documents, all unknown words are **ignored**. So you'll be left with a document using only *known* words, and it will return the best matches for that subset of your document's words.

More fundamentally, a `Doc2Vec` model is really only learning ways to contrast the documents that are in the universe demonstrated by the training set, by their words' cooccurrences. If presented with a document with either totally different words, or words whose frequencies/cooccurrences are totally unlike anything seen before, its output will be essentially random, without much meaningful relationship to other more-typical documents. (That'll be maybe-close, maybe-far, because in a way the training on the 'known universe' tends to fill the whole available space.)

So, you wouldn't want to use a `Doc2Vec` model trained **only** only positive examples of what you want to recognize, if you also want to recognize negative examples. Rather, include all kinds, then remember the subset that's relevant for certain in/out decisions – and use that subset for downstream comparisons, or multiple subsets to feed a more-formal classification or clustering algorithm.