# My Doc2Vec code, after many loops/epochs of training, isn't giving good results. What might be wrong?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I'm training a `Doc2Vec` model using the below code, where `tagged_data` is a list of `TaggedDocument` instances I set up before:

```py
max_epochs = 40

model = Doc2Vec(alpha=0.025, 
                min_alpha=0.001)

model.build_vocab(tagged_data)

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    print('iteration {0}'.format(epoch))
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
    # decrease the learning rate
    model.alpha -= 0.001
    # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

model.save("d2v.model")
print("Model Saved")
```

When I later check the model results, they're not good. What might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Do not call `.train()` multiple times in your own loop that tries to do `alpha` arithmetic.**

It's unnecessary, and it's error-prone.

Specifically, in the above code, decrementing the original `0.025` alpha by `0.001` forty times results in (`0.025 - 40*0.001`) `-0.015` final `alpha`, which would also have been negative for many of the training epochs. But a negative `alpha` *learning-rate* is nonsensical: it essentially asks the model to nudge its predictions a little bit in the *wrong* direction, rather than a little bit in the *right* direction, on every bulk training update. (Further, since `model.iter` is by default 5, the above code actually performs `40 * 5` training passes – `200` – which probably isn't the conscious intent. But that will just confuse readers of the code & slow training, not totally sabotage results, like the `alpha` mishandling.)

There are other variants of error that are common here, as well. If the `alpha` were instead decremented by `0.0001`, the 40 decrements would only reduce the final `alpha` to `0.021` – whereas the proper practice for this style of SGD (Stochastic Gradient Descent) with linear learning-rate decay is for the value to end "very close to `0.000`"). If users start tinkering with `max_epochs` – it is, after all, a parameter pulled out on top! – but don't also adjust the decrement every time, they are likely to far-undershoot or far-overshoot `0.000`.

So don't use this pattern.

Unfortunately, many bad online examples have copied this anti-pattern from each other, *and* make serious errors in their own `epochs` and `alpha` handling. Please don't copy their error, and please let their authors know they're misleading people wherever this problem appears.

The above code can be improved with the much-simpler replacement:

```py
max_epochs = 40
model = Doc2Vec()  # of course, if non-default parameters needed, use them here
                   # most users won't need to change alpha/min_alpha at all
                   # but many will want to use more than default `epochs=5`

model.build_vocab(tagged_data)
model.train(tagged_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=max_epochs)

model.save("d2v.model")
```

Here, the `.train()` method will do exactly the requested number of `epochs`, smoothly reducing the internal effective `alpha` from its default starting value to near-zero. (It's rare to need to change the starting `alpha`, but even if you wanted to, just setting a new non-default value at initial model-creation is enough.)

Also: note that later calls to `infer_vector()` will reuse the `epochs` specified at the time of model-creation. If nothing is specified, the default `epochs=5` will be used - which is often smaller than is best for training or inference. So if you find a larger number of `epochs` (such as 10, 20 or more) is better for training, remember to also use at least the same number of `epochs` for inference. (`.infer_vector()` takes an optional `epochs` parameter whihc can override any value set at model-contruction.