# Checking model overfit of doc2vec with infer_vector()

Tags: python, testing, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

my aim is to create document embeddings from the column df["text"] as a first step and then as a second step plug them along with other variables into a XGBoost Regressor model in order to make predictions. This works very well for the train_df.
I am currently trying to evaluate my trained Doc2Vec model by inferring vectors with infer_vector() on the unseen test_df and then again make predictions with it.However, the results are super bad. I got a very large error (RMSE).
I assume, this means that Doc2Vec is massively overfitting?
I am actually not sure if this is the correct way to evaluate my doc2vec model (by infer_vector)?
What to do to prevent doc2vec from overfitting?

Please find my code below for infering vectors from a model:

```
vectors_test=[]
for i in range(0, len(test_df)):
    vecs=model.infer_vector(tokenize(test_df["text"][i]))
    vectors_test.append(vecs)
vectors_test= pd.DataFrame(vectors_test)
test_df = pd.concat([test_df, vectors_test], axis=1)
```

I then make predictions with my XGBoost model:

```
np.random.seed(0)
test_df= test_df.reindex(np.random.permutation(test_df.index))

y = test_df['target'].values
X = test_df.drop(['target'], axis=1).values

y_pred = mod.predict(X)
pred = pd.DataFrame()
pred["Prediction"] = y_pred
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y,y_pred))
print(rmse)
```

Please see also the training of my doc2vec model:

```
doc_tag = train_df.apply(lambda train_df: TaggedDocument(words=tokenize(train_df["text"]), tags= [train_df.Tag]), axis = 1)

# initializing model, building a vocabulary 

model = Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=200, min_count=1, window=10, workers= cores) 

model.build_vocab([x for x in tqdm(doc_tag.values)])

# train model for 5 epochs 

for epoch in range(5): 
    model.train(utils.shuffle([x for x in tqdm(doc_tag.values)]), total_examples=len(doc_tag.values), epochs=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what your `XGBoost` model is being trained to predict, or more about the type/quantity of your training data for certain steps, it's hard to speculate why one particular set of inputs are performing poorly. (For example, it could equally be the `XGBoost` model's data, parameters, or training that's mismatched to the task.)

But, some observations:

- You generally shouldn't be calling `train()` multiple times in your own loop. See [My Doc2Vec code, after many loops of training, isn't giving good results. What might be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62801052/130288) for discussion of common problems here. (Yours isn't quite as stark, but the learning-rate isn't being handled properly in your 5 separate `train()`s - indeed there should even be some error in your log output.)
- Similarly: it's often a bad idea to use a `min_count` so small as `1` in these kinds of models: such rare words, without enough varied examples to be truly understood, just inject idiosyncratic noise which dilutes the influence of other, surrounding tokens which are meaningful.
- Most published work trains a `Doc2Vec` model for 10-20 epochs – you're only using 5. (And, for smaller datasets or smaller texts, often even more epochs help.) Inference will also default to the epochs configured when the model was created – here only 5 – but more epochs are often beneficial.
- It's unclear the size of your training texts and their unique vocabulary, but `Doc2Vec` overfitting will be most likely if the model is relatively large – in terms of `vector_size` or total surviving vocabulary – compared to the training data. Then, the model has lots of opportunity to essentially 'memorize' idiosyncracies of the training set, instead of more-generalizable patterns that will still be useful for out-of-training data. (For example, `min_count=1`, if it's preserving many singleton words which appear in only one text each, gives the model lots of "nooks and crannies" in which to improve its training target results in ways unlikely to help on other examples.) If your training data is "small", you likely need to use a smaller `vector_size` and a larger `min_count` to avoid overfitting, and then perhaps more `epochs` to ensure adequate training.
- `infer_vector` essentially ignores any words not in its vocabulary - so you should take a look at some of the specific texts in the set performing poorly, and check whether most of their words are present, or not. But note also: as `Doc2Vec` is an unsupervised method, a plausible case can be made for training it to learn textual patterns on *all* available data, including the texts in your 'test' set. Then, it is more likely to have some word data, top at least the `min_count` threshold, for words across all examples. (Of course the actual supervised predictor itself can only be fairly evaluated on test examples whose desired answers weren't provided during the predictor's training. But it still can receive its features from an unsupervised step that used all text data.)
- a crude check of a `Doc2Vec` model for overfitting or other training problems (but not overall quality) is to re-infer doc-vectors from the same texts it was trained on, and checking the model's set of bulk-trained vectors (`model.docvecs`) for the nearest-neighbors to these re-inferred vectors. If the re-inferred vector's nearest neighbor isn't usually the same text's bulk-trained vector – or if more generally, re-inferring the same text multiple times doesn't yield vectors that are 'close' to each other – then something about the model training or inference is deficient: overfitting, or undertraining, or insufficient data, or unwise parameters.