# Low accuracy rate after training Doc2Vec model

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, gensim, doc2vec

I'm trying to train a Doc2Vec model in order to create a multi-label text classifier.
In order to do that, i have chosen a data set that contains approximately 70000 article, and every article contains between 1500 and 2000 words.
These articles are divided into 5 classes.
while setting up my input, i chosen as tag for my document their corresponding label.
I have done it as follow :
`tagged_article = data.apply(lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=r['article'].split(), tags=[r.labels]), axis=1)`
then i have trained my model with the following line codes:

```
model_dbow = Doc2Vec(dm=1, vector_size=300, negative=5, min_count=10, workers=cores)
model_dbow.build_vocab([x for x in tqdm(tagged_article.values)])

print("Training the Doc2Vec model for ", no_epochs, "number of epochs" )
for epoch in range(no_epochs):
     model_dbow.train(utils.shuffle([x for x in tqdm(tagged_article.values)]),total_examples=len(tagged_article.values), epochs=1)
     model_dbow.alpha -= 0.002
     model_dbow.min_alpha = model_dbow.alpha
```

After that I have created a logistic regression model in order to predict tags for every article.

To do that I have created the following functions:\

```
def vec_for_learning(model, tagged_docs):
sents = tagged_docs.values
targets, regressors = zip(*[(doc.tags[0], model.infer_vector(doc.words, steps=inference_steps)) for doc in tqdm(sents)])
return targets, regressors

y_train, X_train = vec_for_learning(model_dbow, tagged_article)

logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',max_iter=1000)
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Unfortunately i am getting a very bad result. In fact I'm getting 22% as accuracy rate and 21 % as an F1 score

Can you please explain me why i am getting these bad results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First & foremost, you almost certainly don't want to use your own loop to call `train()` multiple times while managing `alpha` yourself. See: [My Doc2Vec code, after many loops of training, isn't giving good results. What might be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801052/my-doc2vec-code-after-many-loops-of-training-isnt-giving-good-results-what-m/62801053#62801053)

As you don't show your `no_epochs` value, I can't be sure you're doing the absolute worst thing - eventually decrementing `alpha` to a negative value – but you might be. Still, there's no need for that error-prone loop. (And, you may want to contact whatever source suggested this code template to you and let them know they are promoting an anti-pattern.)

It is probably also a mistake to use your just 5 known-labels as the document-tags. That means the model is essentially only learning 5 doc-vectors, as if all articles were just fragments of 5 giant texts. While it's sometimes helpful to use (or add) known-labels as tags, the more classic manner of training `Doc2Vec` gives each document a unique ID, so the model is learning (in your case) about 70,000 distinct doc-vectors, and may more richly model the document-possibility spaces spanned, in various irregular shapes, by all your documents and labels.

While your data is certainly of a size comparable to published work that shows the value of the `Doc2Vec` algorithm, your corpus isn't gigantic (and it's unclear how large & diverse your vocabulary might be). So it's possible that 300 dimensions is oversized for the quanitity/variety of data you have, or `min_count=10` too aggressive (or not aggressive enough) in trimming less-important & less-well-sampled words.

Finally, note that the `Doc2Vec` class will inherit a default `epochs` value of 5, but most published work uses 10-20 training epochs, and often with smaller datasets even more can be helpful. Additionally, inference will reuse the same `epochs` set (or defaulted) at model creation, and works best with (at least) the same number of `epochs` as training - while it's unclear what `inference_steps` you're using.

(As a separate matter of code legibility: you've named your model `model_dbow`, but by using `dm=1` you're actually using PV-DM mode, **not** PV-DBOW mode.)

Comment: In fact i have used the default value of alpha, so i guess it will become negative after some epochs.
i will try to apply all your remark and i hope it become better

Comment: Just one last question: can I use for example as tag for each document a list that contains two values such as for example the document_id and its label ?

Comment: Yes, the `tags` must be a list, but in the classic case it's a list with just one element, a unique document ID. But you can add another tag, such as a known label. Whether that helps or hurts the overall model is something you'd have to test. Having 2 tags will essentially double training effort in true DBOW mode. (If your hope in providing these is to get a single summary doc-vector for each label, note that such reduction of complex category-shapes in the vector space to just a single point may gloss-over the actual ranges of varied document-themes within the category.)