# In correct answer from doc2vec

Tags: python, doc2vec

I execte doc2vec model for text similarity
my code and not obtain reslt

```py
it = LabeledLineSentence(datafiles, labels1)
    
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(vector_size=300, min_count=0, alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025)
model.build_vocab(it)
    
#training of model

for epoch in range(100):
    print ('iteration '+str(epoch+1))
    model.train(it,total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.epochs)
    
    model.alpha -= 0.002
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha
    
#saving the created model
model.save('doc2vec.model')
print ("model saved")
    
#loading the model
d2v_model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load('doc2vec.model')
    
#start testing
seed_text = "consider illegal immoral plagiarism do various"
tokens1 = seed_text.lower().split()
vector1 = d2v_model.infer_vector(tokens1)
    
#to get most similar document with similarity scores using document-index
most_similar = d2v_model.docvecs.most_similar(positive = [vector1] )
    
# output_sentences(most_similar)
print(u'%s %s: %s\n' % ("Most", most_similar[0][1], data[int(most_similar[0][0])]))
```

It output

Most 0.14691241085529327: M

why not print data bt only M what mean , what can i do to solve the problem
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of `LabeledLineSentence` that doesn't match the code that used to be in Gensim. Your version is taking an extra `labels1` argument. So, it's non-standard and you should show its code or explain what online example you're basing your code on. Similarly, it's not clear what the values, or indirect contents, of `datafiles` and `labels1` might be.

The `M` in the output is the result of your code `data[int[most_similar[0][0])]`. Your code doesn't show what `data` is, but perhaps it's a string, and the character `M` is in whatever position `int(most_similar[0][0])` evaluates to.

(The value of `most_similar[0][0]` should be the document-tag that's most-similar to your inferred text-vector, which might be an int or string, depending on how you prepared your training data, in the unshown `LabeledLineSentence` code. There must have been a document in the trining set with that as a tag.)

The number `0.14691241085529327` is the amount of similarity. That's not very much, so your probe inferred text isn't very similar to any training document. (Perhaps that's indicative of some other problem.)

Your code also shows a few bad practices:

- calling `train()` more than once & using non-default `min_alpha` you're manipulating yourself - see answer [My Doc2Vec code, after many loops of training, isn't giving good results. What might be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801052/my-doc2vec-code-after-many-loops-of-training-isnt-giving-good-results-what-m/62801053#62801053) for more details
- setting `min_count=0` - almost always a bad idea, `Doc2Vec` & similar algorithms benefit from ignoring rare words
- using a large `vector_size=300` - this would only be appropriate with some very large training corpus, the kind you'd most likely use a much-larger-than-default `min_count` on, and attempt only after gaining success with smaller experiments

I suggest you *not trust or use* whatever online article motivated this code, & instead start from examples inside the Gensim docs, gradually building them towards your need.

Other generic good steps:

- enable logging at the INFO level, watch the output: it may hint at steps that aren't behaving (via progress counts or timing) the way they should
- double-check your inputs, especially the `it` you've created.

For example, if you run:

```
first_item = next(iter(it))
print('tags: %s\nwords: %s' % (first_item.tags, first_item.words))
```

Does it print the 1st document you intended to use as training material, with the right words and tags? If not, you've got problems in your data source.