# Doc2Vec __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, doc2vec

instantiated the Doc2Vec model like this

```
mv_tags_doc = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize_clean(D), tags=[str(i)]) for i, D in enumerate(mv_tags_corpus)]

max_epochs = 50
vector_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(size=vector_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                dm=0)
  
model.build_vocab(mv_tags_doc)
```

but getting error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest version of the Gensim library that you appear to be using, the parameter `size` is now more consistently `vector_size` everywhere. See the 'migrating to Gensim 4.0' help page:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#1-size-ctr-parameter-is-now-consistently-vector_size-everywhere

Separately, if you're consulting any online example with that outdated parameter name, and which also suggested that unnecessary specification of `min_alpha` and `alpha`, there's a good chance the example you're following is a bad reference in other ways.

So, also take a look at this answer: [My Doc2Vec code, after many loops of training, isn't giving good results. What might be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801052/my-doc2vec-code-after-many-loops-of-training-isnt-giving-good-results-what-m/62801053#62801053)