# Problem in tqdm function in a Doc2Vec model

Tags: python, nlp, doc2vec, tqdm

I am using this article https://actsusanli.medium.com/ to implement the Doc2Vec model and I have a problem in the training step.

```
model_dbow.train(utils.shuffle([x for x in tqdm(train_tagged.values)]), total_examples=len(train_tagged.values), epochs = 40)
```

As you can see, I am using the tqdm function. When I ran the code the tqdm is 100%, after some minutes, but the algorithm still runs in the same shell for a long time.

**Do you have any idea if this is a problem of tqdm function or something else?**

Comment: I guess after the progress bar reaches the end (100%) the actual training process would begin. In fact, python first evaluates the arguments then runs the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the "list comprehension" (`[`..`]`)...

```
[x for x in tqdm(train_tagged.values)]
```

...you are having `tqdm` iterate once over your `train_tagged.values` sequence, into an actual in-memory Python list. This will show the `tqdm` progress rather quickly – then completely finish any involvement with `tqdm`.

Then, you're passing that plain result list (without any `tqdm` features) into `Doc2Vec.train()`, where `Doc2Vec` does its `epochs=40` training passes. `tqdm` is no longer involved, so there'll be no incremental progress-bar output.

You might be tempted to try (or have already tried) something that skips the extra `list` creation, passing the `tqdm`-wrapped sequence directly in like:

```
corpus = utils.shuffle(train_tagged.values)
model_dbow.train(tqdm(corpus), total_examples=len(corpus), epochs = 40)
```

But this has a different problem: the `tqdm`-wrapper is only designed to allow (& report the progress of) *one* iteration over the wrapped sequence. So this will show that one iteration's incremental progress.

But when `.train()` tries its next necessary 39 re-iterations, to complete its `epochs=40` training-runs, the single-pass `tqdm` object will be exhausted, preventing full & proper training.

Note that there is an option for progress-logging within Gensim, by setting the Python logging level (globally, or just for the class `Doc2Vec`) to `INFO`. `Doc2Vec` will then emit a log-line showing progress, within each epoch and between epochs, about every 1 second. But: you can also make such logging less-frequent by supplying a different seconds value to the optional `report_delay` argument of `.train()`, for example `report_delay=60` (for a log line every minute instead of every second).

If you really want a progress-bar, it should possible to use `tqdm` - but you will have to work around its assumption that the iterable you're wrapping with `tqdm()` will only be iterated over once.

I believe there'd be two possible approaches, each with different tradeoffs:

(1) Instead of letting `.train()` repeat the corpus N times, do it yourself - adjusting the other .`train()` parameters accordingly. Roughly, that'd mean changing a line like...

```
model.train(corpus, total_examples=len(corpus), epochs=40)
```

...into something that turns your desired 40 epochs into something that looks like just *one* iteration to both `tqdm` & Gensim's `.train()`, like...

```
repeated_corpus = itertools.chain(*[corpus]*40)
repeated_len = 40 * len(corpus)
model.train(tqdm(repeated_corpus, total=repeated_len), total_examples=repeated_len, epochs=1)
```

(Note that you now *have* to give `tqdm` a hint as to the sequence's length, because the one-time chained-iterator from `itertools.chain()` doesn't report its own length.)

Then you'll get one progress-bar across the whole, training corpus - which the model is now seeing as one pass over a larger corpus, but ultimately involves the same 40 passes.

You'll want to reinterpret any remaining log lines with this change in mind, and you'll lose a chance to install your own per-epoch callbacks via the model's end-of-epoch callback mechanism. (But, that's a seldom-used feature, anyway.)

(2) Instead of wrapping the corpus with a single `tqdm()` (which can only show a progress-bar for one-iteration), wrap the corpus as a new *fully-re-iterable object* that itself will start a *new* `tqdm()` each time. For example, something like:

```
class TqdmEveryIteration(object):
    def __init__(self, inner_iterable):
        self.inner_iterable = inner_iterable
    def iter(self):
        return tqdm(inner_iterable)
```

Then, using this new extra `tqdm`-adding wrapper, you should be able to do:

```py
corpus = utils.shuffle(train_tagged.values)
model_dbow.train(TqdmEveryIteration(corpus), total_examples=len(corpus), epochs = 40)
```

In this case, you should get one progress bar *per epoch*, because a new `tqdm()` wrapper will be started each training pass.

(If you try either of these approaches & they work well, please let me know! They should be roughly correct, but I haven't tested them yet.)

Separately: if the article from the author at `actsusanli.medium.com` that you're modeling your work on is...

https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-doc2vec-logistic-regression-9da9947b43f4

...note that it's using an overly-complex & fragile anti-pattern, calling `.train()` multiple times in a loop with manual `alpha` management. That has problems as [described in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801052/my-doc2vec-code-after-many-loops-of-training-isnt-giving-good-results-what-m/62801053#62801053). But that approach *would* also have the side-effect of re-wrapping the corpus each time in a new `tqdm` (like the `TqdmEveryIteration` class above), so despite its other issues, would achieve one actual progress-bar each call to `.train()`.

(I sent the author a private note via Medium about a month ago about this problem.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your long explanation! I use the code from this article, however I didn't use this techique with a, since as you have already mentioned there are some issues.