# 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'outputs', while saving doc2vec for tensorflow serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving, doc2vec

I have been trying to save a movie recommendation model from github to then serve using tf-serving.
The code below will first create a list of taggs from my corpus and then provide me vectors based on those lists

```
mv_tags_doc = [TaggedDocument(words=(D), tags=[str(i)]) for i, D in enumerate(mv_tags_corpus)]

max_epochs = 50
vec_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(alpha=alpha, 
               min_alpha=0.00025,
               min_count=1,
               dm=0) # paragraph vector distributed bag-of-words (PV-DBOW)
 
model.build_vocab(mv_tags_doc)

print('Epoch', end = ': ')
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
 print(epoch, end = ' ')
 model.train(mv_tags_doc,
             total_examples=model.corpus_count,
             epochs=model.epochs)
 # decrease the learning rate
 model.alpha -= 0.0002
 # fix the learning rate, no decay
 model.min_alpha = model.alpha
```

When I try saving it using the documentation available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple)

```
import tempfile

MODEL_DIR = tempfile.gettempdir()
version = 1
export_path = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, str(version))
print('export_path = {}\n'.format(export_path))

tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    export_path,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None,
    options=None
)

print('\nSaved model:')
!ls -l {export_path}
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_563154/3914941631.py in <module>
      6 print('export_path = {}\n'.format(export_path))
      7 
----> 8 tf.keras.models.save_model(
      9     model,
     10     export_path,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/saving/saving_utils.py in try_build_compiled_arguments(model)
    319 def try_build_compiled_arguments(model):
    320   if (not version_utils.is_v1_layer_or_model(model) and
--> 321       model.outputs is not None):
    322     try:
    323       if not model.compiled_loss.built:

AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'outputs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect the `tf.keras.models.suave_model()` function – which sounds from its naming to be specific to TensorFlow & Keras – to work on a Gensim `Doc2Vec` model, which is not part of, or related to, or built upon either TensorFlow or Keras.

Looking at the [docs for `save_model()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model), I see its declared functionality is:

> Saves a model as a TensorFlow SavedModel or HDF5 file.

Neither "TensorFlow SavedModel" nor "HDF5 file" should be expected as sufficient formats to save another project's custom model (in this case a Gensim `Doc2Vec` object), unless it specifically claimed that as a capability. So some sort of failure or error here is expected behavior.

If you real goal is to simply be able to re-load the model later, don't involve TensorFlow/Keras at all. You could either:

1. use Python's internal `pickle` mechanism, or
2. use the [`.save(fname)` method native-to model classes in the Gensim package](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.save), which uses its own `pickel`-and-`numpy`-based save format. For example:

```py
filename = 'my_doc2vec_model'
initial_model.save(filename)
```

Note that such saves may be spread over several related files alongside each other, all starting with the same string you provided, which should be kept together. (That is, after the code above, be sure to keep any and all files that begin with the string `'my_doc2vec_model'` together.)

You'd then re-load by calling `.load()` on the expected model class:

```py
reloaded_model = Doc2Vec.load(filename)
```

Separately: your Doc2Vec code shows a number of bad practices. Using such a low `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea, slowing training & worsening results, with this sort of algorithm. And decrementing the `alpha` yourself, in your own loop calling `.train()` multiple times, is [unnecessarily complex & error-prone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801053/130288). Whatever template/tutorial that suggested that approach is probably a bad one.

Comment: can you please suggest what a good practice of parameters will look like in my thanks

Comment: Good parameters is something that varies with your data & goals – so you should generally start by just leaving the defaults in place, unless/until you have (1) discovered a specific trusted recommendation that applies to your needs; and (2) some way to score alternate choices against each other – a repeatable, ideally automated quantititave evaluation of th final results. Then you can tell which recommendations, or changes from your own tinkering, are helping or hurting.